# What's the future of linguistics? Will it be ever...complete?

Tags: syntax

Let's restrict the question to syntax. Will be there a point when all the governing rules behind grammar have been discovered and all phenomena is explained?

Comment: It's an interesting question but unfortunately this question has no definite answer. Usually we [try to avoid these types of questions on SE](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/).

Comment: This question can apply to any field of study. Will *physics* ever be complete? Is it anywhere close to being complete? And remember that humans have been studying physics for thousands of years longer than they've been studying linguistics.

Comment: Well languages don't remain static, they constantly evolve. So we can't really say linguistics will ever be "complete" because languages will never be "complete".

Comment: "Languages" don't exist as such except as individual sets of speech habits and their individual histories of success and adaptation. As for the future of syntax, that's kind of iffy. Certainly there will never be a time when all the rules will have been discovered, because nobody's keeping track of [the rules that have been](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/haj/Preliminarybufattenedlistoftransformations.pdf). They always turn out to be wrong, so they throw them away and start over with a much better theory that is much harder to use; sort of like Windows.

Comment: @jlawler: Haha, the Windows metaphor is dangerous...surely linguists build on the work on giants like everybody else...actually, Windows does that too.

Comment: @acattle: Humans have studied language in abstract terms for as long as we know, at least in Egypt. Psammetichus I already conducted a linguistic experiment, or so reported Herodotus, to find out which language was the oldest in the world. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psamtik_I#Discovering_the_origin_of_language It is only the word linguistics that is fairly new.